# angular2 filter-pipe with many categories and combinations

Tags: javascript, angular, filter

I'm trying to implement an angular 2 filter where the user should able to filter by a set of categories. Where the filtered result should include any object that has at least one field matching one of the categories that the user has chosen to filter by.

As for now I have 2 categories and have been able to do all of this "manually" but now I need to do this with up to 20 categories and I'm looking for a generic way to do this.

Consider this for an example (what I use now to filter by gender):

```
transform(value) {
if(value == null) {
  return null;
}
// NO FILTER AT ALL //////

//If no filter is selected
if(this.SearchService.filterFemale == 0 && this.SearchService.filterMale == 0){
  return value.filter(company => {
    return company;
  });
}
//If Female only
if(this.SearchService.filterFemale !== 0 && this.SearchService.filterMale == 0){
  return value.filter(company => {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < company.audience.targetGroup.genders.length; i++) {
      if(company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Female'){
        return company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Female';
      }
    }
  });
}
//If Male only
if(this.SearchService.filterFemale == 0 && this.SearchService.filterMale !== 0){
  return value.filter(company => {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < company.audience.targetGroup.genders.length; i++) {
      if(company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Male'){
        return company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Male';
      }
    }
  });
}
//If both Male and Female
if(this.SearchService.filterFemale !== 0 && this.SearchService.filterMale !== 0){
  return value.filter(company => {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < company.audience.targetGroup.genders.length; i++) {
      if(company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Female' || company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Male'){
        return company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Female' || company.audience.targetGroup.genders[i].gender === 'Male';
      }
    }
  });
}
}
```

This works fine, however, lets say I have 15-20 categories to filter by and need the same logic this would be a real pain to write the code for with all the possible combinations there are.

For example: If in my case, a company object hold 4 chosen categories and a user then filters by 3 categories out of 15 possible where 2/3 of them match with the 4 categories the company has chosen then that company should be returned. Essentially, I'm looking for the same logic in the example above but it should work with any number of categories.

I've followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423903/angular2-pipe-for-multiple-arguments) in my code. Where it is suggested that this is a similar mechanism as to how **array.prototype.filter** works, though, I can't figure out how I would use it in my example.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hmm, how about passing the categories as an array, then looping through it, inside that loop you will make your filtration and add the accepted items to an array that will eventually contain all items that was accepted from all categories.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try this out and see what I'm able to come up with.